KSH PS1 adding spacing when tabbing
I just started a new job and we have to use KSH. I was customizing my PS1 and have an issue when I start writting and press TAB. It adds a few blank space and continue there.
I don't have the reputation to post pictures, so I post here the output when writing ls then pressing TAB:
[bob@mycomputer /auto/home/bob]$ ls                              ls Desktop/
Desktop/      Downloads/    Pictures/     Templates/    bin/          dot_save/     plop.log      test/

I know it is a well known problem in ZSH, needs to add some %{} around colors, but I don't think this exists in KSH.
This is my .kshrc:
RED=$'\033[0;31m'
GREEN=$'\033[0;32m'
BLUE=$'\033[0;34m'
CYAN=$'\033[0;36m'
RESET=$'\033[0m'

PS1="${CYAN}[\`whoami\`@\`hostname\` ${BLUE}\`pwd\`${CYAN}]${RED}\$${RESET} "

I know the problem is with the colors as I tested without colors and it doesn't have this problem.

I found the answer, % can actually work in KSH. You just have to add the line
setopt promptpercent

before your PS1
